# manual zooming in MapKit on iOS

Tags: ios, mapkit, zooming

In my iOS application using MapKit I would like to use only pinch (not double tap) for zooming. I set zoomEnabled=NO, add pinch gesture recognizer and try to manually set map region  coresponding to current pinch size. The problem is that map only displays some zoom levels so I'm unable to achive proper zoom effect. I would appreciate any idea. Thank you.

Comment: As far as i know, `zoomEnabled=NO` will DISABLE the pinch gestures to zoom in and out of the map. You want to recognize the pinch level manually? I don't think you need to set `zoomEnabled` to `NO`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go the other way. Rather than disabling zoom and then rewriting it, why not add a double tap gesture recogniser and make it do nothing. But then again, why would you take that feature away from users? If someone doesn't have the manual dexterity to pinch but they can double-tap, you'll have broken the map for them.

Comment: In my app I would like use taping for painting the map. If the user taps too quickly map zooms which is very disturbing. So ideally I would like to disable doule-tap-zooming and leave only pinch-zooming. The problem is setting zoomEnaled=NO disables both and I have problem implementing pich-zooming manually. If I try other way - unfortunatelly gestures recognizers don't work in zoom is enabled